# How to prevent tests from evaluating with TestCreate?

Tags: testing-and-verification

When I am creating a test for example with TestCreate, I have input and expected output. How can I prevent the expected input from evaluating the output? This was one of my favorite areas of new functionality expanded in 13.3. For example, if I have a function ResistanceMatrix, how can I test that it produces the same output as GraphData's "ResistanceMatrix" for the "PetersenGraph"?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered how to do this after reading Stephen Wolfram's release announcement for 13.3 section [Symbolic Testing Framework](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica#symbolic-testing-framework).
The solution is to use the scoping construct With in Table, which effectively uses the scoping construct Block to do something similar to Map with pure functions over a list. There might also be a way to make it work with Unevaluated.

```wl
tests = Table[
  With[{i = i, j = i + 1}, 
   TestCreate[i + 1, j, TestID -> Automatic]], {i, 4}]
```

Then run

```wl
TestReport[tests]
```

and I get

```wl
TestReportObject[<|"Title" -> Automatic, "Aborted" -> False, 
  "TestResults" -> <|3890776590901293718 -> TestObject[\
<|"MetaInformation" -> None, "AbsoluteTime" -> 3.897225378977161*^9, 
       "SameTest" -> SameQ, "SameMessages" -> Testing`MessageMatchQ, 
       "MemoryConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "TimeConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "CreationID" -> "7326579c-2d13-4115-9260-e18d1f282685", 
       "TestID" -> "65cf6dc6-313b-4a30-aea7-56478682fef1", 
       "TestFileName" -> "", 
       "EvaluationID" -> "e5b3960e-021c-411a-bd96-0be9d44821fa", 
       "Input" -> HoldForm[1 + 1], "ExpectedOutput" -> HoldForm[2], 
       "ExpectedMessages" -> HoldForm[{}], 
       "ActualOutput" -> HoldForm[2], "ActualMessages" -> {}, 
       "AbsoluteTimeUsed" -> 0``7.150514997831988, 
       "CPUTimeUsed" -> 0., "MemoryUsed" -> 2496, 
       "Outcome" -> "Success"|>], 
    1792103122768780638 -> TestObject[<|"MetaInformation" -> None, 
       "AbsoluteTime" -> 3.897225378977161*^9, "SameTest" -> SameQ, 
       "SameMessages" -> Testing`MessageMatchQ, 
       "MemoryConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "TimeConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "CreationID" -> "a22068e2-9c71-4a71-9008-f0d99a773acd", 
       "TestID" -> "579065fe-1adc-4b27-a0b8-9593b8799da1", 
       "TestFileName" -> "", 
       "EvaluationID" -> "25f33fd3-48d3-4c91-9411-055c8801a08d", 
       "Input" -> HoldForm[2 + 1], "ExpectedOutput" -> HoldForm[3], 
       "ExpectedMessages" -> HoldForm[{}], 
       "ActualOutput" -> HoldForm[3], "ActualMessages" -> {}, 
       "AbsoluteTimeUsed" -> 0``7.150514997831988, 
       "CPUTimeUsed" -> 0., "MemoryUsed" -> 2128, 
       "Outcome" -> "Success"|>], 
    4195592839575175517 -> TestObject[<|"MetaInformation" -> None, 
       "AbsoluteTime" -> 3.897225378977161*^9, "SameTest" -> SameQ, 
       "SameMessages" -> Testing`MessageMatchQ, 
       "MemoryConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "TimeConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "CreationID" -> "32d336ce-ff2f-4b5d-94c6-04e8caa6ec0d", 
       "TestID" -> "4acc8da8-24c3-4ac8-a06b-1f62d806f4ad", 
       "TestFileName" -> "", 
       "EvaluationID" -> "356aa29f-3c40-4827-badb-0e81421ca2db", 
       "Input" -> HoldForm[3 + 1], "ExpectedOutput" -> HoldForm[4], 
       "ExpectedMessages" -> HoldForm[{}], 
       "ActualOutput" -> HoldForm[4], "ActualMessages" -> {}, 
       "AbsoluteTimeUsed" -> 0``7.150514997831988, 
       "CPUTimeUsed" -> 0., "MemoryUsed" -> 2128, 
       "Outcome" -> "Success"|>], 
    2729069003583258653 -> TestObject[<|"MetaInformation" -> None, 
       "AbsoluteTime" -> 3.8972253789781694`*^9, "SameTest" -> SameQ, 
       "SameMessages" -> Testing`MessageMatchQ, 
       "MemoryConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "TimeConstraint" -> DirectedInfinity[1], 
       "CreationID" -> "4b329be3-7805-4728-a822-93404350b0ff", 
       "TestID" -> "d1b274ad-cc2c-453b-a15f-a15ffb5008d7", 
       "TestFileName" -> "", 
       "EvaluationID" -> "c23dc937-e49e-41a5-b926-412c94c64174", 
       "Input" -> HoldForm[4 + 1], "ExpectedOutput" -> HoldForm[5], 
       "ExpectedMessages" -> HoldForm[{}], 
       "ActualOutput" -> HoldForm[5], "ActualMessages" -> {}, 
       "AbsoluteTimeUsed" -> 0``7.150514997831988, 
       "CPUTimeUsed" -> 0., "MemoryUsed" -> 2128, 
       "Outcome" -> "Success"|>]|>, "FailureResults" -> <||>, 
  "TestsNotEvaluatedKeys" -> {}, "TestsFailedWrongResultsKeys" -> {}, 
  "TestsFailedWithMessagesKeys" -> {}, "TestsFailedWithErrorsKeys" -> {},
   "TestsSucceededKeys" -> {3890776590901293718, 1792103122768780638, 
   4195592839575175517, 2729069003583258653}|>]
```

To add echos showing the individual tests, do

```wl
TestReport[tests, HandlerFunctions -> <|"TestEvaluated" -> Echo|>]
```

Here's another example where I want to test that my function ResistanceMatrix produces the same output as GraphData's "ResistanceMatrix" property for the Petersen graph implemented as "PetersenGraph" with GraphData.

```wl
tests = Table[
  With[{input = input, 
    output = GraphData[input, "ResistanceMatrix"]},
   TestCreate[ResistanceMatrix[GraphData[input]], output, 
    TestID -> Automatic]], {input, {"PetersenGraph"}}]
```

Then I run the tests.

```wl
TestReport[tests]
```

I can also echo.

```wl
TestReport[tests, HandlerFunctions -> <|"TestEvaluated" -> Echo|>]
```